# Don't Know How To Proceed

Tags: candy-box-2

Alright...
I've beaten myself,
killed a troll,
got a crown,
and a whole bunch of other stuff.

I'm stuck at the forest.
What on Earth are you supposed to do?

For clarification:

I have the monkey staff, the cauldron, the enchanted red gloves, the enchanted pink gloves, the feather, the introspection boots, and both grimoires.

Comment: Have you enchanted the crown?

Comment: Oh, which enchantment should I take?

Comment: Up to you! You can always go back and beat another Octopus to get another.

Comment: Alright, that's all done! I assume now it's just eat candies until I can tank past the guards?

Comment: Get the jasper enchant btw. The obsidian one spawns king octopus who block you from moving. Really annoying.

Comment: If you get the pogo stick in the mountains, you can usually jump over the octopus kings if they're in your way. Sometimes they stack up too high though! Then usually if you teleport *then* jump, you can get past them.

Comment: @emfg I have some hilarious screenshots of this when I grinded for a few hours, I'll see if I can link them

Answer (score 2):

Click on the asterisk by the cave entrance to get the pogo stick, which allows you to jump. Once you have that, use acid rain to kill a bird in the desert and get the Desert Bird Feather which makes you jump a bit higher. Now, you *should* be able to jump over the Wolves and Ent looking thingies in the forest. If not, equip your Red Leather Gloves, and with the Monkey staff, which you need to enchant, you spew fireballs everywhere. You should now be able to complete the forest.

Here is the Pogo Stick:

[image: Here is the location of the Pogo Stick.]

Source of photo:[Where is the asterisk for a pogo stick on candy box 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/138891/where-is-the-asterisk-for-a-pogo-stick-on-candy-box-2)