# Where is the asterisk for a pogo stick on candy box 2?

Tags: candy-box-2

I know it's by The Cave Entrance, but I don't know where is it EXACTLY. Can somebody show me or show me a way to find it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In most browsers you should be able to ctrl-f to find where the asterisks are.  I've taken a screenshot, though, to help you.

[image: Asterisk Location]

Comment: I thought it would be nearer the cave entrance thanks

Comment: Weaksauce... they wanted to know where the pogo stick was. Not how to defeat the purpose of the asterisks being hidden in ascii... I down voted as its a solution. But not the answer.